# xQuery value returns null for valid XML tags

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery-sql

I have multiple XMLs in the following format:

```
<Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition">
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="DataSource1">
      <DataSourceReference>/DataSources/Infinite</DataSourceReference>
      <rd:DataSourceID>RandomID</rd:DataSourceID>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="DataSet1">
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>DataSource1</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText>HCC.RPTUnderwriter</CommandText>
        <rd:UseGenericDesigner>true</rd:UseGenericDesigner>
      </Query>
    </DataSet>
    <DataSet Name="DataSet2">
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>DataSource1</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText>HCC.RptUnderwriterList</CommandText>
        <rd:UseGenericDesigner>true</rd:UseGenericDesigner>
      </Query>
    </DataSet>
  <rd:ReportID>randomReportIDx</rd:ReportID>
  <rd:ReportServerUrl>http://sampleRS/ReportServer</rd:ReportServerUrl>
</Report>
```

Below is the SQL code I am using to convert the 'Cat.Content' into an XML and then extract the 'Datasource' name and 'CommandText'. The issue I am having is that for some XMLs, it returns the correct value for the 'Datasource' and 'CommandText' fields, however, there are some XMLs that return NULL even though there is a value in the 'Datasource' and 'CommandText' fields. I am trying  to figure out why it works on some XMLs and not on others. The XMLs are mostly in the same format and order and there are a few that have an additional namespace.

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES 
( DEFAULT 
  'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition',
  'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner' AS RF
)

SELECT  
    CATDATA.Name AS ReportName
    ,CATDATA.Path AS ReportPathLocation,
    catdata.reportXML as ReportXml
    ,xmlcolumn.value('(@Name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') AS DataSetName  
    ,xmlcolumn.value('(Query/DataSourceName)[1]','VARCHAR(250)') AS DataSourceName 
    ,xmlcolumn.value('(Query/CommandText)[1]','VARCHAR(2500)') AS CommandText
    from (
        select 
            Cat.Name, 
            cat.Path, 
            convert (xml, convert (varbinary(max),cat.content)) as reportXML, 
            Cat.Content
        from ReportServer.dbo.Catalog Cat
        where cat.Content is not null
        and cat.type = 2
        ) catdata
outer APPLY reportXML.nodes('/Report/DataSets/DataSet') xmltable ( xmlcolumn )
ORDER BY CATDATA.Name;
```

EDIT:
This is the XML that DOES NOT WORK with the current SQL query:

```
<Report 
  xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition">
      <DataSources>
        <DataSource Name="DataSource1">
          <DataSourceReference>/DataSources/Infinite</DataSourceReference>
          <rd:DataSourceID>RandomID</rd:DataSourceID>
        </DataSource>
      </DataSources>
      <DataSets>
        <DataSet Name="DataSet1">
          <Query>
            <DataSourceName>DataSource1</DataSourceName>
            <CommandText>HCC.RPTUnderwriter</CommandText>
            <rd:UseGenericDesigner>true</rd:UseGenericDesigner>
          </Query>
        </DataSet>
        <DataSet Name="DataSet2">
          <Query>
            <DataSourceName>DataSource1</DataSourceName>
            <CommandText>HCC.RptUnderwriterList</CommandText>
            <rd:UseGenericDesigner>true</rd:UseGenericDesigner>
          </Query>
        </DataSet>
    <DataSets>
      <rd:ReportID>randomReportIDx</rd:ReportID>
      <rd:ReportServerUrl>http://sampleRS/ReportServer</rd:ReportServerUrl>
    </Report>
```

This is the XML that WORKS with the current query:

```
<Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns:cl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/componentdefinition" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition">
  <AutoRefresh>0</AutoRefresh>
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="Infinite">
      <DataSourceReference>/DataSources/Infinite</DataSourceReference>
      <rd:DataSourceID>DSRAndomID</rd:DataSourceID>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="DataSet1">
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>Infinite</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText>HCC.RPTBrokerState</CommandText>
        <rd:UseGenericDesigner>true</rd:UseGenericDesigner>
      </Query>
    </DataSet>
    <DataSet Name="DataSet2">
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>Infinite</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText>HCC.RptStateList</CommandText>
        <rd:UseGenericDesigner>true</rd:UseGenericDesigner>
      </Query>
    </DataSet>
  </DataSets>
</Report>
```

Comment: First, you've got an error in your XML as posted; the `</DataSets>` close tag is missing. Second, as you can see from the XML, the default namespace in the query (`http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition`) doesn't match the namespace used in the XML (`http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition`). Although generally the use of a namespace wildcard is frowned upon, if you don't want to make things really complicated switching on multiple versions I think it's an acceptable use here (`/*:Report/*:DataSets/*:DataSet` etcetera).

Comment: Namespaces matter. The default namespace on `Report` is actually `http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition`.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: @JeroenMostert For the namespace, I will need both the 2010 and 2008 report definition. The wildcard does not seem to work for me. Is there a way to default both versions?


WITH XMLNAMESPACES 
( default 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition' as RDef10,
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition' as RDef08,
  'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner' AS RDef

Comment: @Maria, Please add "not working" XML sample(s) to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> however, there are some XMLs that return NULL even though there is a
> value in the 'Datasource' and 'CommandText' fields. I am trying to
> figure out why it works on some XMLs and not on others. The XMLs are
> mostly in the same format and order and there are a few that have an
> additional namespace.

Please try the following solution for the provided XML. You would need to add "not working" XML sample(s) to your question.

All elements in the XML are bound to a different default namespace in different rows. That's why I am using a namespace wildcard as @JeroenMostert already suggested.

Both XQuery methods `.nodes()` and `.value()` are using a namespace wildcard in the XPath expressions.

And the `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` clause is commented out.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
(N'<Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition">
    <DataSources>
        <DataSource Name="DataSource1">
            <DataSourceReference>/DataSources/Infinite</DataSourceReference>
            <rd:DataSourceID>RandomID</rd:DataSourceID>
        </DataSource>
    </DataSources>
    <DataSets>
        <DataSet Name="DataSet1">
            <Query>
                <DataSourceName>DataSource1</DataSourceName>
                <CommandText>HCC.RPTUnderwriter</CommandText>
                <rd:UseGenericDesigner>true</rd:UseGenericDesigner>
            </Query>
        </DataSet>
        <DataSet Name="DataSet2">
            <Query>
                <DataSourceName>DataSource1</DataSourceName>
                <CommandText>HCC.RptUnderwriterList</CommandText>
                <rd:UseGenericDesigner>true</rd:UseGenericDesigner>
            </Query>
        </DataSet>
    </DataSets>
    <rd:ReportID>randomReportIDx</rd:ReportID>
    <rd:ReportServerUrl>http://sampleRS/ReportServer</rd:ReportServerUrl>
</Report>')
, (N'<Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner"
        xmlns:cl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/componentdefinition"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition">
    <AutoRefresh>0</AutoRefresh>
    <DataSources>
        <DataSource Name="Infinite">
            <DataSourceReference>/DataSources/Infinite</DataSourceReference>
            <rd:DataSourceID>DSRAndomID</rd:DataSourceID>
        </DataSource>
    </DataSources>
    <DataSets>
        <DataSet Name="DataSet1">
            <Query>
                <DataSourceName>Infinite</DataSourceName>
                <CommandText>HCC.RPTBrokerState</CommandText>
                <rd:UseGenericDesigner>true</rd:UseGenericDesigner>
            </Query>
        </DataSet>
        <DataSet Name="DataSet2">
            <Query>
                <DataSourceName>Infinite</DataSourceName>
                <CommandText>HCC.RptStateList</CommandText>
                <rd:UseGenericDesigner>true</rd:UseGenericDesigner>
            </Query>
        </DataSet>
    </DataSets>
</Report>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

--WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition')
SELECT ID
    , c.value('@Name', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS [Name]
    , c.value('(*:Query/*:DataSourceName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS DataSourceName
    , c.value('(*:Query/*:CommandText/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS CommandText
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/*:Report/*:DataSets/*:DataSet') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+----------+----------------+------------------------+
| ID |   Name   | DataSourceName |      CommandText       |
+----+----------+----------------+------------------------+
|  1 | DataSet1 | DataSource1    | HCC.RPTUnderwriter     |
|  1 | DataSet2 | DataSource1    | HCC.RptUnderwriterList |
|  2 | DataSet1 | Infinite       | HCC.RPTBrokerState     |
|  2 | DataSet2 | Infinite       | HCC.RptStateList       |
+----+----------+----------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: For the "INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata) VALUES", how will that work when I have multiple xmls? I can't copy and paste for all the XMLs that I have, that is why I converted the content. Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: @Maria, The answers follow the same **minimal reproducible example** pattern. You copy it to SSMS as-is, and it works. You can easily add 2nd, and 3rd XML samples to the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: @Maria, Please don't worry about it. Just add few XML samples to your original question.

Comment: I just added the XMLs. Also, would the insert statement work for multiple XMLs? I have over 100 XMLs to extract from.

Comment: @Maria, (1) I updated the answer. (2) You don't need to `INSERT` anything. The **DDL and sample data population** section is just to reproduce/mimic your environment in the answer.

Comment: @Maria, please connect with me on LinkedIn.